# Updating ngIf through array iteration. Making a simple slide show

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-ng-if, two-way-binding

I was playing around with creating my own image slide show and started playing around with arrays. I'm wasn't sure how to approach this problem, so I set ngIf's in each element that I wanted to show and hide, set values in the class for each, then pulled those into an array.

I think that's where I'm going wrong, but I don't see it. I can get the slideShow function to update each Array element to True through each iteration, but I'm not sure what to return. I think I'm missing something really simple, but I'm not sure what.

Here's the stackblitz **UPDATED WITH ANSWER**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ydflj

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
  })
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    slider1 = true;
    slider2 = false;
    slider3 = false;
    slider4 = false;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.slideShow();
    }
    slideShow() {
      const time = 2000;
      const slideArray = [this.slider1, this.slider2, this.slider3, this.slider4];

      for (const images in slideArray) {
        if (images) {
          timeout(images);
        }
      }
      function timeout(images) {
        window.setTimeout(() => {
          slideArray[images - 1] = false;
          slideArray[images] = true;
          console.log(slideArray[images], images, slideArray);
        }, time * images);
        return slideArray[images];
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define **slideArray** as a component class property

```
// probably just above constructor
slideArray = [this.slider1, this.slider2, this.slider3, this.slider4];
```

Then in **timeout** function:

replace all `slideArray` with `this.slideArray`

When you call `timeout(images);`, do it as `timeout.call(this, images);`

After you finish all above, `slideArray` will be the return value and be avaible in the component html file

Comment: I amended my answer with a new step to call ```timeout(images)```

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I'm still getting an error. I updated the stackblitz would you mind taking a quick look. I may have an error I'm not seeing. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ydflj

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, instead of ```timeout(images).call()```, it should be ```timeout.call(this, images);```

Comment: working link from stackblitz is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbj9tg?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Sweet, I should have known that call should chain off of the function. So then how do I update the this.slider1 and so on?

Comment: Since ```slideArray``` has elements that reference to ```this.slider1``` and so on, so timeout function will update each ```this.slider1```, and you can directly use ```slider1``` etc in html, they are already the return values :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208820/discussion-between-rostasan-and-yuchao-wu).